# Skipping heading levels in reStructuredText

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, heading

Is it possible in some way to skip heading levels in RestructuredText? For example, given

```
####
PART
####

*******
Chapter
*******

Section
=======

Subsection
----------

Subsubsection
^^^^^^^^^^^^

Paragraph
"""""""""

Another section
===============

Another Paragraph
"""""""""""""""""
The above heading seems to be rendered as a subsection-level heading...
```

The last paragraph gets rendered as a subsection instead of as a paragraph. (I am using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) as a renderer.) So it seems section-level detecting is local, although the [RestructuredText documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#sections) says it should be consistent:

> All section title styles need not be used, nor need any specific
>   section title style be used. However, a document must be consistent in
>   its use of section titles: once a hierarchy of title styles is
>   established, sections must use that hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

When running Sphinx 1.3 on the document in the question, a warning is emitted:

```
C:\path\to\test.rst:24: SEVERE: Title level inconsistent:
```

"Another Paragraph" is on line 24 and it gets rendered as a subsection heading because that is what Sphinx expects at that position.

So no, you cannot skip heading levels. That is also how I interpret the meaning of the passage about consistency quoted in the question.

Comment: Mark, that SEVERE is the highest message severity level. In Docutils, it leads to aborting the conversion by default (configurable with the [halt_level](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#report-level) setting). So this is more than just a *warning*.