# Hide Heading Level in Sphinx Restructured Text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I inherited an existing RST document with the following structure:

```
DocTitle
========

Heading2
--------

Heading1
========
```

Note that `Heading1` is a larger heading than `Heading2`.  Due to the fact that I am now adding this document to a TOC, I want it to be properly indented.  That means changing the title to a new heading, such as the following:

```
DocTitle
########

Heading2
--------

Heading1
========
```

The problem is that the above makes `Heading2` larger than `Heading1`.  Is there some way to define a heading style without adding an actual heading to the page?  For example, I want to do something like:

```
DocTitle
########

.. hidden::
   Heading1
   ========

Heading2
--------

Heading1
========
```

Is there any way to achieve this result in an RST file?

Related question:
    [Skipping heading levels in reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149169/skipping-heading-levels-in-restructuredtext)

The answer to that question is "no", but I wonder if there is a way to define a heading that is hidden from the resulting output.

Comment: Perhaps `rubric` is what you are looking for? http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-rubric

Answer (score 0):

Hiding an element in the HTML output is possible with custom CSS, e.g.

```
DocTitle
########

.. rst-class:: hide-me

dummy section heading
=====================

Heading2
--------

Heading1
========

.. contents::
.. sectnum::
```

together with the CSS rule `section.hide-me > h2 {display: none;}`.

Notes:

- The dummy section is still in the output and shown in the ToC. It also affects section numbering.
- A "section heading" in the rST source actually creates a [`<section>`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#section) Document Tree node with nested [`<title>`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#title) element. `<section>` and `<title>` elements don't have a "level" attribute – the section level is derived from its nesting level.
- The "class" value is added to the `<section>` element, not its `<title>`.
  Subsections are nested in the parent `<section>`, too. Removing the element classified as "hide-me" would also remove the subsection with title "Heading2".

Compiling the original document with Docutils will use both top-level headings as section headings leaving the document without document title.
With Sphinx, both headings have the same level, too, but the first is also used for the document metadata title.

How about keeping the titles at the same level with an additional "super title" for the document?
You can also just set a custom "metadata document title" with the ["title" directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#metadata-document-title).