# Invisible heading in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm trying to have the following kind of layout in a Sphinx document :

---

## Title

#### Article 1

### Section 1

#### Article 2

---

I already saw that no matter what symbols I use to underline or overline the headers, the first appearance of a given heading will determine its hierarchical relation to the others. I.e, the following won't work :

```
==========
Title
==========

Article 1
---------

---------
Section 1
---------

Article 2
---------
```

Is there a way to circumvent this, for example by defining an invisible "Section 0" heading between **Title** and **Article 1** with dashes as underline and overline, so that sphinx understands that Sections are greater than Articles, without actually displaying a "Section 0" between the title and the first article ?

I'm trying to do something like this [Skipping heading levels in reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149169) - although I don't really understand the code example they give...

Answer (score 0):

The only ugly solution I found is the following :

```
=====
Title
=====

-----
 \
-----

Article 1
---------
...
```

The two issues are that it creates a blank gap in the resulting document, and that it inserts a title-less heading in the toctree at the index page (even though it does not do that in the local summary).